# Read parquet file compressed with zstd

Tags: file-io, julia, parquet, zstd

I am new to Julia and I am trying to port some stuff I did in Python.

I have a file I wrote in Python, with a DataFrame to a **parquet** file using the **zstd** compression lib (supported by both **pandas** and **fastparquet**, parquet file writing).

It gives an error since **ParquetFiles** or **FileIO** (not sure which one is responsible for the decompression), doesn't support **zstd**.

Any ideas on how to read this file in Julia?

```
using DataFrames
using ParquetFiles
using FileIO

test = DataFrame(load("test.parquet"))
```

> ```
> Unknown compression codec for column chunk: 6  
> Stacktrace:
>  [1] error(::String) at ./error.jl:33 
>  [2] bytes at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/reader.jl:149 [inlined]  
>  [3] bytes at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/reader.jl:140 [inlined]  
>  [4] values(::ParFile, ::Parquet.Page) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/reader.jl:232  
>  [5] values(::ParFile, ::Parquet.PAR2.ColumnChunk) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/reader.jl:178  
>  [6] setrow(::ColCursor{Int64}, ::Int64) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/cursor.jl:144  
>  [7] ColCursor(::ParFile, ::UnitRange{Int64}, ::String, ::Int64) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/cursor.jl:115  
>  [8] (::getfield(Parquet, Symbol("##11#12")){ParFile,UnitRange{Int64},Int64})(::String) at ./none:0  
>  [9] collect(::Base.Generator{Array{AbstractString,1},getfield(Parquet, Symbol("##11#12")){ParFile,UnitRange{Int64},Int64}}) at ./generator.jl:47  
>  [10] RecCursor(::ParFile, ::UnitRange{Int64}, ::Array{AbstractString,1}, ::JuliaBuilder{ParquetFiles.RCType361}, ::Int64) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Parquet/qSvbc/src/cursor.jl:269 (repeats 2 times)  
>  [11] getiterator(::ParquetFiles.ParquetFile) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/ParquetFiles/cLLFb/src/ParquetFiles.jl:74 
>  [12] nondatavaluerows(::ParquetFiles.ParquetFile) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Tables/IT0t3/src/tofromdatavalues.jl:16  
>  [13] columns at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/Tables/IT0t3/src/fallbacks.jl:173 [inlined]  
>  [14] #DataFrame#393(::Bool, ::Type, ::ParquetFiles.ParquetFile) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/DataFrames/VrZOl/src/other/tables.jl:34  
>  [15] DataFrame(::ParquetFiles.ParquetFile) at /home/morgado/.julia/packages/DataFrames/VrZOl/src/other/tables.jl:25  
>  [16] top-level scope at In[25]:8
> ```

Comment: Have you tried https://github.com/bicycle1885/CodecZstd.jl?